# React Native - Push one Screen To Another have issue

Tags: react-native, react-router, react-navigation, react-native-0.46

I used the '`StackNavigator`', I have issue to push when navigation code write in button event. but its working fine if we directly code onPress event,

Import file.

```js
import { StackNavigator } from "react-navigation";
import SignUpScreen from "./SignUp";
```

**Push another is working :**

```js
render() {
    console.disableYellowBox = true;
    const { navigate } = this.props.navigation;
    return (
       <View style={styles.viewStyle}>
         <TouchableHighlight style = {styles.buttonStart}
             onPress={() => navigate("SignUpCompany")}>
               <Image
                 source={require('./Images/hire.png')}
               />
         </TouchableHighlight>
       </View>
    );
  }
```

**Push another via function is not working :**

```js
   pushcode() {
     console.log('call');
     this.props.navigation.navigate('SignUp');
   }

   render() {
    return (

     <TouchableHighlight style = {styles.buttonStart}
         onPress={this.pushcode}>
           <Image
             source={require('./Images/hire.png')}
           />
     </TouchableHighlight>

    );}
```

**ERROR ON CLICK BUTTON :**

[image]

Thanks. Please help me.

Answer (score 2):

Look like you are using the push extra in this line

```
this.props.navigation.navigate.push('SignUp');
```

Try this will work for you

```
this.props.navigation.navigate('SignUp');
```

May be this can help you

Comment: what problem I didn't get you ?

Answer (score 1):

I think you miss the function `bind` within constructor --- that's why you got **undefined is not an object (evaluating 'this.props.navigation')**. because `this` is undefined inside `pushcode` function scope.

add below into your constructor:

```js
constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.pushcode = this.pushcode.bind(this);
    ...
}
```